# When would it be appropriate to use logging?

Tags: java, log4j

[Feasible to start writing unit test in an old project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578581/feasible-to-start-writing-unit-test-in-an-old-project) I had asked a question here about starting unit testing in an old code that shows the structure of the project.

Now the project has log4j and I am very new to it. So while eyeballing the source code there was some `logging` with message `In Donation Servlet`.

Don't remember the exact syntax but something like,

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SearchServlet.class);
log.info("In XYZ Servlet");
```

So my question is where would logging be useful. Is it stored in log files for future reference? I am really a noob when it comes to libraries that I can't get the bigger picture here. I can guess that this is just for information thats why the `info()` combining with methods like `debug()`, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Go read the docs - http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

Comment: Is your question about when to use log4j, or when to do logging? Your title says one thing, your question another.

Comment: Broadly asking about logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging is useful for
1. debugging of new code
2. troubleshooting of code in production
3. monitoring of production application using third party or home made tools

etc, etc.

Typically logs are written to files. However it depends on configuration of your logging framework. Log4j is the oldest and wider used java logging framework. BTW FYI it is deprecated by its creator that implemented new logger named LogBack and light weight wrapper named SLF4j. So, if you are just starting I'd recommend you to switch to SLF4j.

Concerning to configuration. Take a look in this [tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). It covers most of issues. Do not hesitate to ask again if you have concrete questions. I hope my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In general logging helps you understanding what happened inside your application in the past. 
Consider a customer tells you that he faced a bug in your application that caused his data to be lost. If you are not able to reproduce this issue for whatever reason good logging information can help you a lot finding such an issue.

Typically log entries should at least contain a timestamp and a useful message. Be aware that the message you found (`In xyz servlet`) is **not** an example of a useful message.

Log4J isn't hard to use. I think AlexR covered everything necessary about log4j so I don't have anything to add :-)

Comment: Thanks, will try to add something more meaningful (I am thinking of the state during exceptions) using it.